# NestJS Swagger: Edit route name

Tags: swagger, nestjs, documentation

I have an endpoint like this:

```
@Controller(['route1', 'route2'])
export class test {

  @Post('endpoint')
  public test() { return; }

}
```

The swagger than generates two routes:
'/route1/endpoint' and '/route2/endpoint'

I would like this to only generate one endpoint in the swagger documentation of '/endpoint', but then say in the documentation above the different routes the user can use to call the endpoint. Is there any way I can edit these and only show one?

Comment: I don't think there's a non-hacky way to exclude one. You can exclude the controller with `@ApiExcludeController()` class decorator. Or the route with `@ApiExcludeEndpoint()` method decorator.

Comment: you can request this feature at https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues btw

Comment: Do you have a hacky way of doing this?

Comment: nope :/ I'm pretty can change the schema that will be generated somehow

Comment: Yeah.. do you know if this is possible either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338988/nestjs-swagger-create-multiple-public-private-internal-etc-swagger-pag?

Comment: I didn't dig too much into `@nestjs/swagger` code, so I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller('route1')
export class test {

  @Post('endpoint')
  public test() { return; }

}
will return ->> base_url/route1/endpoint
```

```
@Controller()
export class test {

  @Post('endpoint')
  public test() { return; }

}
will return ->> base_url/endpoint
```

you can also use global prefix for all routes for example
`app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');`
then endpoint will be `base_url/api/v1/route1/endpoint`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**