# NestJS Swagger: Create multiple 'public', 'private', 'internal', etc swagger pages

Tags: swagger, nestjs, decorator, document

I need to create multiple swagger places for different groups. I'd like to be able to add a decorator to some endpoint, such as '@Private', and then that endpoint is included in that specific swagger.

I can do something like '@ApiExcludeEndpoint()' for individual endpoints, but this removes it from all created swagger documents.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is add a tag to the operations I wanted to hide, then remove all operations with that tag from the OpenAPIObject returned by the createDocument function.

e.g.:

```
export const InternalTag = 'Internal';

/**
 * Removes route or controller from public swagger
 */
export const IsInternal = () => ApiTags(InternalTag);

export function filterInternalRoutes(doc: OpenAPIObject) {
  const publicDoc = structuredClone(doc);
  Object.entries(publicDoc.paths).map(([k, path]) => {
    Object.entries(path).forEach(([k, operation]) => {
      const op = operation as OperationObject;
      if (op.tags?.includes(InternalTag)) delete path[k]; // delete the op from the public doc;
    });
  });
  return publicDoc;
}
```

And in my bootstrap I just did the following:

```
const doc = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig);
const publicDoc = filterInternalRoutes(doc);

SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, publicDoc);
SwaggerModule.setup('docs/internal', app, doc);
```

Thus removing all paths which I don't want to be on the public doc.